# change Material UI Typography into styled-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Is it possible to convert Material UI elements

```
<Container component="main" maxWidth="XS">
```

```
<Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
```

into styled-components?

I tried this for typography but the text appears to be much smaller.

```
export const Typo = styled.h5`
```

```
export const Typo = styled(Typography)`
component: h1; 
variant: h5;
`
```

Another example: I tried using this but the `mt: 8`doesn't work either. I am also unable to import Box from material ui systems so just tried this method after seeing an example.

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

export const StyledBox = styled(Box)`
mt: 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [@material-ui/system](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/)

> `@material-ui/system` provides low-level utility functions called "style functions" for building powerful design systems.

Use it with styled-component

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { palette, spacing, typography } from '@material-ui/system';

const Box = styled.div`${palette}${spacing}${typography}`;
```

For **typography**

Refer the demo here: https://material-ui.com/system/typography/#typography

---

#### Update

If we only want to style material-ui component with `styled-components`

Import from normal **@material-ui/core** would be fine

```
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const StyledTyppgraphy = styled(Typography)`
  ...
`;
```

Refer: document of styled-components [Extending Styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is this typography styled the same way that normal Material UI core typography is styled like? So should I just fill in component/variant values in it? I couldn't find any such example. Also, pls see the updated qs

Comment: As mentioned in the qs, I have already tried this but it doesn't work properly. Even if I use the same styling properties, the results are a bit different. Maybe I need to use something else except variant and component inside the styled-component

Answer (score 0):

As @keikai already pointed out, you can [extend styles](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles).

I've made a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-hugle-vg3k8?file=/src/App.js) with a few examples. 
You can just import the component and use it like this:

```
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)``;

<StyledTypography variant="h5" component="h1"></StyledTypography>
```

Without adding custom styles, both `Typography` and `StyledTypography` should look the same.

[Typography example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-hugle-vg3k8?file=/src/Typography/Typography.styled.js) (with custom color)

```
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
const StyledBox = styled(Box)``;

<StyledBox mt={8}></StyledBox>
```

[Box example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-hugle-vg3k8?file=/src/Box/Box.styled.js)

Note that I included an optional way of working with Material UI spacing variables.

Like mentioned in the [Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#create-a-component), you can also use spacing props by importing `spacing` from `@material-ui/system`. That way you can apply these spacing props without extending a Material UI component.
You can also use the spacing function directly in a styled component, but that's beyond the scope of this question I think.